# Swift how can I make this function async to get rid of my application warning

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftsoup

I am using SwiftUI 4.0 and have the SwiftSoup package . When I try to load a website I now get this message (happens for any website)

> Synchronous URL loading of https://www.cnn.com should not occur on
> this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
> Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

It specifically occurs during this section of the code

```
if let html = try? String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8) {
```

does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this issue . This is the function I am using

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import SwiftSoup

func NewLinkRequest(_ LinkUrl: String) ->(LinkUrl: String ,LinkTitle: String ,LinkImage: String)
{
    var newTitle = ""
    
    
    let urlm = URL(string: LinkUrl)
    
    guard let myURL = urlm else {
        return ("","Failed to get url", "")
    }
    
    if let html = try? String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8) {
        
        do {
            let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
            let headerTitle = try doc.title()
            
            let firstImage = try doc.select("img").attr("src")
            
            newTitle = headerTitle
            
            
            return (LinkUrl,newTitle, firstImage)
            
            
        } catch Exception.Error( _, let message) {
            print("Message: \(message)")
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        return ("","", "")
    } else {
        
        return ("","Failed to get url", "")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

This error happens because `String(contentsOf: )` is synchronous and can cause your UI to hang. Instead, use a `URLSession` like below. The following function, given a `URL`, will **asynchronously** get you the `String`.

### The Solution

```swift
func fetchFromURL(_ url: URL) async -> String{
   let session = URLSession.shared
   let (theStringAsData, _) = try await session.data(from: articleUrl)
   if let returnableString = String(data: theStringAsData, encoding: .utf8)  
   {
       return returnableAsString
   } else {
       return ""
   }
}
```

### Code breakdown:

1. `let session` is the shared `URLSession` for your application - docs here: [`URLSession.Shared`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared)
2. `let (theStringAsData, _)` returns a `Data` object and a `URLResponse` - docs for this method here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data
3. We check to ensure this data is not nil, and if the typecast to `String` works, we return the new `String`. Otherwise, we return an empty.

### Example Usage:

```swift
import SwiftSoup

   Task{
       let theString = fetchFromURL(URLHERE) //Put your URL here!
       //We use a do/catch block here because SwiftSoup.parse can throw
     do{
        let document = try SwiftSoup.parse(theString) //This is now the parsed document if it worked
        print(document)
     } catch { //SwiftSoup failed to parse the String into a document, so we need to handle the error
         print("Failed to parse")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the issue and now I know why .